# Port Conflict Issue When Running Next.js Project Simultaneously on Local and Remote Server

Tags: next.js, pm2

I'm currently developing a Next.js project, running the development server on localhost:3000 using VSCode in my local environment. Simultaneously, I'm connected to a remote server (Ubuntu server) via VSCode's Remote Explorer, where I'm hosting a website using PM2 with a different port and domain.

Accidentally, I attempted to run the Next.js project on the remote server as well, using the `npm run dev` command, despite the fact that the production website was already hosted on port 4000 using PM2. Subsequently, when I tried to run the project again locally, the web browser kept loading infinitely when trying to access localhost:3000.

To address this issue, I attempted the following steps:

Initially, I checked if there were any processes using port 3000 on the remote server by running the following command:

`sudo netstat -tuln | grep 3000`

However, it didn't return any results.
How can I resolve this situation? Is there a way to run the Next.js project simultaneously on both local and remote servers?